# TypeError: value.animate is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was trying to make this simple little audio player for my brother's website as his current one is not very nice.

So, I have in HTML a few grey boxes which I thought would be nice to have animated (moving to represent music beats). This is what the html looks like. I have one div with the id of reference-box so I can find its siblings easily in jQuery. Also, they have a 'h' value which represents the hight they will be animated to go to... so far I'm doing it like that, but I'm planning on making it rdm after:

```
<div class='greybox' id='reference-box'></div>
<div class='greybox' data-h='15'></div>
<div class='greybox' data-h='5'></div>
<div class='greybox' data-h='7'></div>
<div class='greybox' data-h='2'></div>
<div class='greybox' data-h='15'></div>
```

This is how I find, and store the siblings with jQuery:

```
var $boxes = $('#reference-box').siblings('.greybox');
```

I then loop through all the elements in a function which is called once the player is un-paused:

```
function animateBars(){ 
    if (audio.paused === false){ //Check if the audio is paused (stops if it is therefor)
        $.each($boxes, function(index, value){
            console.log(heightToBecome + " || " + index + " || Boxed Length: " + $boxes.length + " || Box Element: " + value);

            value.animate({
                height: "5px"
            }, "slow");

            //Do the animations (above and below)

            value.animate({
                height: "15px"
            }, "slow", animateBars);
        });
    }
}
```

However, I get this problem:

> TypeError: value.animate is not a function. (In 'value.animate({
>                           height: "5px"
>                       }, "slow")', 'value.animate' is undefined)

I've looked at other posts, but most I don't understand, and others didn't work.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`value` is a DOMElement, not a jQuery object. Use `$(value)` when trying to call jQuery methods on the element.

```
$.each($boxes, function(index, value) {
    var $value = $(value); // create the jQuery object...

    console.log(heightToBecome + " || " + index + " || Boxed Length: " + $boxes.length + " || Box Element: " + value);

    // ... then use it to perform the animations
    $value.animate({
        height: "5px"
    }, "slow");

    //Do the animations (above and below)

    $value.animate({
        height: "15px"
    }, "slow", animateBars);
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked. I'm only a beginner in jQuery... wasn't aware of that. Thank you for the fast reply too!

Comment: No problem, glad to help